# Combining Kaufman efficiency ratio with price density

Tags: python, dataframe, algorithm

I am trying to combine the Kaufman efficiency ratio with inverted price density and store the results into a data frame.

The trouble I'm having is with the price density code. What am I doing wrong, the output from the data frame is the same value over the entire dataframe and the outputs suggest that it's just the kaufman.

```
[code]
`
`# calc the Kaufman Efficiency ratio
def ker(src, p, dir):
    akauf = src - src.shift(p) if dir else np.abs(src - src.shift(p))
    bkauf = np.sum([np.abs(np.array(src.shift(ikauf)) - np.array(src.shift(ikauf + 1))) for ikauf in range(p)], axis=0)
    er = akauf / bkauf
    return er

#normalize function
def normalize_data(data):
    min_val = data.min()
    max_val = data.max()
    if min_val == max_val:
        return 0  # Avoid division by zero
    return (data - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)

# inverted price density
def inverted_price_density(high, low, period):
    numer_pd = np.sum(high - low)
    deno_pd = np.max(high) - np.min(low)
    if deno_pd == 0:
        return 0  # Avoid division by zero
    result_pd = numer_pd / deno_pd
    return 1 / result_pd

# Input paras
KERPD_period = 20
KERPD_dy_baseline = 0.35
KERPD_dy_cal = 0.35

# Calc kaufman Efficiency Ratio based on the Close price
result_kauf = ker(data['Close'], KERPD_period, False)
norm_result_kauf = normalize_data(result_kauf)

# Calculate inverted price density
result_pd = inverted_price_density(data['High'], data['Low'], KERPD_period)
norm_price_density = normalize_data(result_pd)

print(result_pd)

# Store unfiltered Kaufman and price density in data frame
data['result_kauf'] = result_kauf
data['result_pd'] = result_pd
# Merge Kaufman Efficiency Ratio and Inverted Price Density
kerpd_merge = (norm_result_kauf + norm_price_density) / 2
# Dynamic Line Control
horz_line = norm_result_kauf * KERPD_dy_baseline
horz_line_a = (1 - norm_result_kauf) * KERPD_dy_cal

# Add KERPD Noise Filter values to the existing DataFrame
data['KERPD_Noise_Filter'] = kerpd_merge
data['KERPD_Background_Noise_Baseline'] = horz_line
data['KERPD_Background_Noise_Bouyancy'] = horz_line_a

# Plotting
plt.plot(kerpd_merge, color='aqua', label='KERPD Noise Filter')
plt.axhline(y=horz_line.iloc[-1], color='red', linestyle='--', label='KERPD Background Noise Baseline %')
plt.axhline(y=horz_line_a.iloc[-1], color='teal', linestyle='--', label='KERPD Background Noise Bouyancy %')

plt.legend()
plt.show()

data.tail(50)
`
```

Debugging print to try and pinpoint source` of issue[/code]